# VS2017 Heap Profiling does not work due to Internet Explorer

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I have a C++ Application developed using Visual Studio 2017.

I would like to locate memory leaks using the Heap Profiling feature which is part of diagnostic tools. I can easily take snapshots of the heap, and I can see cumulative differences, but then I want to pinpoint the details of leaftover memory allocations. Unfortunately when I cleck on the links or when I want to inspect the heap, Visual Studio shows me a black page saying:

"The Content requires a new version of Internet Explorer"

I then click on the link for the message and I find myself in a microsoft webpage stating that:
"If you’re running Windows 10, you already have Internet Explorer 11, so there’s nothing you need to install. However, Microsoft Edge is a brand-new browser that also comes with Windows 10, and what’s more, it’s your default browser. Be sure to check it out!"

I jsut checked  and I have Internet Explorer AND Edge Installed... both of them appear to be updated to most recent versions.

I see there is an [open issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85063/heap-snapshot-reports-the-content-requires-a-new-v.html) on the VS support site but it is under investigation since July.

Is this really such a rare issue?
Any help is appreciated, I already tried to fake IE version in registry as suggested in similar issues, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: I had this problem too with 15.3.5. I've just updated to 15.4.2 and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like VS has been having problems with both Diagnostic Tools and Heap Profiling unable to open and presenting this error message. Microsoft has had a couple of stabs at fixing both issues already in:

- [Diagnostic Tools empty content window](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40028/diagnostic-tools-empty-content-window.html)
- [Heap Snapshot reports 'The content requires a new version of Internet explorer'](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85063/heap-snapshot-reports-the-content-requires-a-new-v.html)

Have a read through both links to see if any of the provided information can help you resolve the problems (I suspect mshtml.dll issues in the first link).

Comment: following the status of one of this 'bug reports' as well